# Proving Corollary to Riesz's Lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed linear space and $Y \leqslant X$ be a proper subspace. If $\text{dim}(Y) < \infty$, show that there exists $x \in X$, with $\|x\| = 1$ such that $d(x,Y) = 1$.

Note $d(x,Y) := \inf_{y\in Y}d(x,y)$ for all $x \in X$.

I am aware of the Reisz's lemma and this is a corollary of the result. I do not see how to proceed here. Hints, tips are requested.

Comment: You may be interested to see also this : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1675944/254733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in X\setminus Y$ (such an element exists, since $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$). Since $Y$ is finite dimensional, there is $y\in Y$ such that 
$d(x,Y)=\|x-y\|>0$. Then $\displaystyle z=\frac{x-y}{\|x-y\|}$ is a unit vector in $X$ and:

$$d(z,Y)=\frac{1}{\|x-y\|}d(x-y,Y)=\frac{1}{\|x-y\|}d(x,Y)=1.$$

Edit. Regarding the equality $d(x-y,Y)=d(x,Y)$: we have:

$$d(x-y,Y)=\inf\{\|(x-y)-z\|:~z\in Y\}=
\inf\{\|x-(y+z)\|:~z\in Y\}\overset{!}=
\inf\{\|x-w)\|:~w\in Y\}=d(x,Y)$$
-Note that at the equality ! we used the fact that $Y$ is a subspace of $X$. Since $y\in Y$, the sets $\{x-(y+z):~z\in Y\},~\{x-w:~w\in Y\}$ are equal (and therefore the sets $\{\|x-(y+z)\|:~z\in Y\},~\{\|x-w\|:~w\in Y\}$ are equal).

Comment: Could you explain the last equality of $d(x-y,Y)$ and $d(x,Y)$?

Comment: why there is $y\in Y$ such that $d(x, Y)=\|x-y\|$?

Comment: @mac There is a sequence $(y_n)$ of $Y$ such that $(\|x-y_n\|)$ converges to $d(x,Y)$. Since on a finite dimensional space, every bounded sequense has a convergent subsequence, for the bounded sequense $(y_n)$ there is a subsequence that converges to some $y\in Y$ and $(\|x-y_{k_n}\|)$ converges to $\|x-y\|$. Therefore you get the equality.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout how do you know the $(y_{n})$ are bounded?

Comment: Since $\|y_n\|\leq \|y_n-x\|+\|x\| $ for all $ n$ and the last part is bounded, while being convergent.